# Repeat query if no results came up

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could someone please advise on how to repeat the query if it returned no results. I am trying to generate a random person out of the DB using `RAND`, but only if that number was not used previously (that info is stored in the column "allready_drawn"). 
At this point when the query comes over the number that was drawn before, because of the second condition `"is null"` it does not display a result.
I would need for query to re-run once again until it comes up with a number.

```
DECLARE @min INTEGER;
DECLARE @max INTEGER;

set @min = (select top 1 id from [dbo].[persons] where sector = 8 order by id ASC);
set @max = (select top 1 id from [dbo].[persons] where sector = 8 order by id DESC);

select 
ordial,
name_surname

from [dbo].[persons]

where id = ROUND(((@max - @min) * RAND() + @min), 0) and allready_drawn is NULL
```

The results (two possible outcomes):

[image]

Any suggestion is appreciated and I would like to thank everyone in advance.

Comment: Why do you restrict the `sector` for `@min` and `@max` but not in the final query?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Good question my friend :) It slipped away from me, because I was focusing on other things, so I forgot all about adding it there as well ... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@gbn that's a correct solution, but it's possible it's too expensive.  For very large tables with dense keys, randomly picking a key value between the min and max and re-picking until you find a match is also fair, and cheaper than sorting the whole table.

Also there's a bug in the original post, as the min and max rows will be selected only half as often as the others, as each maps to a smaller interval.  To fix generate a random number from @min to @max + 1, and truncate, rather than round.  That way you map the interval [N,N+1) to N, ensuring a fair chance for each N.

For this selection method, here's how to repeat until you find a match.

```
--drop table persons
go
create table persons(id int, ordial int, name_surname varchar(2000), sector int, allready_drawn bit)

insert into persons(id,ordial,name_surname,sector, allready_drawn) 
            values (1,1,'foo',8,null),(2,2,'foo2',8,null),(100,100,'foo100',8,null)

go
declare @min int = (select top 1 id from [dbo].[persons] where sector = 8 order by id ASC);
declare @max int = 1+ (select top 1 id from [dbo].[persons] where sector = 8 order by id DESC);


set nocount on
declare @results table(ordial int, name_surname varchar(2000))

declare @i int = 0
declare @selected bit = 0


while @selected = 0
begin
    set @i += 1

    insert into @results(ordial,name_surname)
    select 
    ordial,
    name_surname
    from [dbo].[persons]
    where id = ROUND(((@max - @min) * RAND() + @min), 0, 1) and allready_drawn is NULL

    if @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    begin
       select *, @i tries from @results
       set @selected = 1
    end
end
```

Comment: Mind = blown. Hats down sir Browne :) I learned a lot from this spot-on example! Thank you so much for your time and contribution.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this to remove the "id" filter so you only have to run it once

```
select TOP 1
    ordial,
    name_surname
from [dbo].[persons]
where allready_drawn is NULL
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: I kinda started with NEWID() the first time - but could not polish the query the way I wanted... Solution you posted is very creative, I must say! I did not use it this time because of my huge source table (little bit expensive), but saved this gem to my query treasure chest for some future projects for sure. Thank you so much for your contribution.